# Is it possible to specify an image or list of packages to install on a per-node basis in MAAS?

Tags: juju, maas

Or, is this a job for juju instead?

Answer (score 3):

Per an answer to my original (since edited) [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181507/what-username-password-does-maas-assign-to-nodes) by bigjools, I'm posting his answer here as well. See below... thanks bigjools!

> Is it possible to specify an image or list of packages to install on a per-node basis in MAAS? Or, is this a job for juju instead?

That's a job for Juju.

Comment: The "Juju way" of doing this is by writing a charm and installing the packages you need inside the "install" hook. Then, you can deploy the charm to a specific machine using --constraints.

Answer (score 3):

Another question - [Is it possible to have juju use a MAAS server as the master node?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181635/is-it-possible-to-have-juju-use-a-maas-server-as-the-master-node) -  was marked as an exact duplicate of this, but it is not. I cannot undo that change, so I will answer here for now:

Right now, Juju randomly chooses a node from the pool of machines that MAAS manages. In 12.10 we plan to honour hardware constraints given when a machine is requested from MAAS. Juju should be able to take advantage of that, to target the bootstrap node (referred to as "master node" in the question) to a particular machine.

However, afaik, there aren't any plans to allow users to put the bootstrap node on the machine running MAAS.